# electron ipc renderer to main process - euro sign (€) becomes 'Ôé¼'

Tags: angular, character-encoding, electron, ipc

I have some encoding troubles with a string I am sending from the ipcRenderer to ipcMain within the electron framework.

Renderer process:

```
let test: String = "abc€123";
console.log(test); // prints "abc€123"
electron.ipcRenderer.send('testMessage', test);
```

Main process:

```
ipcMain.on('testMessage', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg); // prints "abcÔé¼123"
});
```

Why is the main process printing the string as "abcÔé¼123"? 
The value gets saved into a database and gets saved as garbage and not the actuall € sign.

Edit: console.log("€") in the main process also shows up 'Ôé¼' in the console

Comment: Then the problem is possibly the way how you work with database and not the code you've posted. Make sure that your files are UTF-8.

Comment: what exactly you mean with my files, the sourcecode .js files?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what happens in your app, but make sure that html is utf8 as well and has proper charset.

Comment: my charset in html is set to utf-8. Also if I put that string manually into the database, it gets stored & loaded afterwards correctly. The file that writes the sql statement also is encoded utf8. any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually was not the encoding. Turned out to be the datatype i used to save it into sql db.

I use the node-mssql and had to change the datatype to NVarChar:

```
request.input('test', db.sql.NVarChar, "€");
```